# Hiding the Navigation Bar in Xamarin Project using Mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using mvvmcross and implementing the view's interface in code behind. I would like to hide the navigation bar but I have not found a solution yet.

I tried

```
NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, false);
```

and

```
NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
```

in different methods (ViewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear) but they don't have an impact on the UI.

Maybe someone could give me a hint. :-)

@Edit: Some more information:

My AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow _window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        _window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var setup = new Setup(this, _window);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        _window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Additionally I'm using a BaseView class which inherits from MvxViewController.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, found the solution by myself:

Just paste the following code into the ViewDidLoad method in your MvxViewController class( for example FirstView.cs in many mvvmcross tutorials):

```
var navController = base.NavigationController;
navController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a +6 years old question but came across finding a solution for this using MVVMCross and found out that using this into the xaml of your view should be enough: `<NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar>False</NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar>`

It should apply for both Xamarin Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This will kill it, let me know if you have questions.

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations
    UIWindow window;
    MyViewController viewController;
    MainViewController mainViewController;
    UINavigationController navController;

    public UINavigationController NavController { get { return navController; }}

    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        var navController = new UINavigationController(); 
        navController.SetNavigationBarHidden (true, false);

        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds); 
        viewController = new MyViewController();

        app.SetStatusBarStyle (UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, true);

        navController.PushViewController(viewController, false);

        window.RootViewController = navController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't implement your solution.
In my AppDelegate.cs I'm using

    `var setup = new Setup(this, _window);
    setup.Initialize();

    var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
    startup.Start();`

and I'm using a abstract BaseView class which inherits from MvxViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The default presenter uses a UINavigationController for the RootController on the window; so you can manipulate the navigation bar globally in the AppDelegate by grabbing it off the window and casting:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    new Setup(this, window).Initialize();
    Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>().Start();

    var navigationBar = ((UINavigationController)window.RootViewController).NavigationBar;
    navigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
    navigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Black;
    navigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;

    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    return true;
}
```